# Audio file served from Web Api and IIS7.5 only plays once in Chrome

Tags: html, asp.net-web-api, html5-audio, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to have my back end serve up a .wav file. When I try to play the wav file in Chrome it will only play once then I either need to reload the page or call .load() on the audio element. Every other browser i've tried on windows will happily play the file again if I press the play button when the audio ends.

my code is pretty simple

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    var path = @"C:\path\a.wav";

    HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

    var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
    result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("audio/wav");
    return result;
}
```

And my html page

```
 <audio id="audio1" controls>
     <source src="api/audio" type="audio/wav">
 </audio>
```

I can serve up this same exact file using other methods like python and chrome will play it over and over again but when I serve the file from Web Api it will only play once. My Web Api is hosted in IIS is there some setting there that needs to be changed?

**Edit**
So I can server the file directly out of IIS and it works fine. I can play the file back over and over. So my problem is with Web Api now. I need to serve the file from a controller to check if the user and logged in and authorization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using Nginx as a back end for my static files. I think serving directly out of IIS was probably a bad idea in the first place.